# How to check if a string is numeric/float in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, string-comparison, string-matching

Here are the validations which I want to apply:

1. The string should contain any character between 0 to 9.
2. It should not contain any alphabetical character.
3. It can contain at most one '-' (minus operator) which will signify a negative number such as "-12".
4. It can also contain at most one '.' to cover the case of floating numbers such as "12.2"

Now I have tried various combinations but still I am unsuccessful to create such a condition in Typescript.
Here's what I tried:

- **using regex** /^[0-9.{0,1}-{0,1}]/.test(mystring)

Unfortunately, this didn't work for me.
Can anyone please help me to get the desired solution?

Comment: Typescript isn't a runtime language.

Comment: @KennethK. I checked my solution with the help of console.log().

Comment: I'm saying that Typescript itself isn't a programming language. Rather, it's (effectively) an enhancement to Javascript that provides for compile-time typing of your Javascript data. So I don't see what Typescript itself has to do with this issue. You have a Javascript problem, and that you should be able to debug with `console`.

Comment: TypeScript isn't a programming language?  Now I'm sad.

Comment: @jcalz I was afraid I'd catch flak for that statement. I'm not sure how to say what I mean  :)

Comment: @DG4 what is your actual use case?  Do you want to verify everything that JavaScript interprets as number (like `1.234e+30`) or just the particular restrictions you mention?

Comment: @KennethK. TypeScript is a preprocessor language that provides strict typing via static analysis during compilation into JavaScript.

Comment: why not `isNaN(parseFloat('-12.2') ? 'Invalid' : 'Valid';` ?

Comment: Is there any check that `Number(val)` that's missing?   @AdityaParab parseFloat will accept `12.3xyz`..

Comment: @Keith yep.. my bad... I also realize that it will also accept `12.....3` and give you 12

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In TypeScript, use the following function which can accept any value:

```
const isFixed = (o: any) => {
  const s = String(o)
  return !isNaN(+s) && isFinite(+s) && (typeof o === 'number' || !/e/i.test(s))
}
```

Or if you're only checking strings:

```
const isFixedString = (s: string) => !isNaN(+s) && isFinite(+s) && !/e/i.test(s)
```

Note that the explicit `String()` casting in the first function is to avoid calling the value's `toString()` or `valueOf()` or `[Symbol.toPrimitive]()` more than once and risk checking conflicting values of auto-updating types like `{ n: 0, valueOf: () => n++ }`.

The casts using the unary `+` operator in both definitions are specifically for the parameter types to be compatible with the global definitions in TypeScript for `isNaN()` and `isFinite()`, which expect a `number` argument for some reason even though JavaScript can handle any type. Otherwise these casts can be removed without any change to the result.

#### Explanation

Just using `!isNaN(mystring)`, you will check whether casting the string with `Number()` will result in `NaN`:

```js
let arr = ['5', '-5', '.5', '5.', '0', '5e0', '5E0', 'Infinity', '-Infinity', '5a', 'n', '--5'];

arr.forEach(str => console.log(str, !isNaN(str)))
```

It should be noted that this approach also accepts scientific notation and `Infinity`, which needs to be handled separately with `isFinite(mystring) && !/e/i.test(mystring)`:

```js
let arr = ['5', '-5', '.5', '5.', '0', '5e0', '5E0', 'Infinity', '-Infinity', '5a', 'n', '--5'];

arr.forEach(str => console.log(str, !isNaN(str) && isFinite(str) && !/e/i.test(str)))
```

Comment: oh! Cool.. I did not know about this `/e/` things.. Scientific notation.. +1

Comment: @AdityaParab `/e/i` is just a RegExp literal that matches strings containing `e` or `E`.

Comment: Understood.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments above, parseFloat will not satisfy all your requirements. And I don't like Reg Ex approach for this kinda things.

The simplest way for you would be to coerce string into a number using unary `+`

```
const stringTransformedToNumber = +"-12.3";

const isInvalid = isNaN(stringTransformedToNumber);

console.log(isInvalid ? 'Invalid' : 'Valid');
```

Even better way is to just use `isNaN`:

```
const isInvalid = isNaN("-12.3");

console.log(isInvalid ? 'Invalid' : 'Valid');
```

Comment: You don't even need to cast it, see my answer.

Comment: Yep... Your answer was posted amidst my posting. :) Good one.

Answer (score -2):

Try sth like this:

`/^\-?(([1-9]\d*)|0)(\.\d+)?$/`

Comment: `5.` and `.5` should be a valid numbers, and they would both fail this check. Easier to just `const isNumber = n => !isNaN(n)`

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)